# elasticsearch foreach to get linked resources

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch schema like below

```
{
    "_index": "index1",
    "_type": "elastic1",
    "_id": "1",
    "_score": 1.4781809,
    "_source": {
      "docnum": 1,
      "linkeddocuments": [{
      "docnum":2, "docname":"mydocname2"},{
      "docnum":3, "docname":"mydocname3"}]
}
```

There are documents as part of the same index with "_id" = 2 and 3 which are basically children of doc id = 1

My query is how do I retrieve details of documents id 2 and 3 by only just passing parent id = 1 in the elastic search query.

Is there a way I could do a "foreach"?

1. get all children (documents) for parent id = 1
2. foreach child id (x) 
   2a. apply some filter on properties of document
3. return docuname and docnum of those which satisfy the criteria

I have a query where I can hardcode the document id list..like below

```
{"query": {
  "bool" :{
        "must": [
          {
            "terms": {
              "docnum": [251,252,253,254]
            }
          }
        ]
        ,
        "filter": 
          {
            "bool": {
              "must" : [
              {"term" :{ "full_name" : {"value" : "Bruce Banner"}}},
              {"terms" :{ "code" : ["HULK","GREEN GIANT"]}},
              {"terms" :{ "country_name" : ["USA","UK"]}}
                ]
            }
          }

    }

}}
```

this works well and the results are as expected..
all I want to do is make the hardcoded list of document ids in the must part..dynamic

Is there a way to do this in elasticsearch without having to do a separate query to get these ids and them pass them in this query?

thanks in advance

Comment: No :-), unless you also index the "parent" ID (if you don't need anything else from it) inside the children as well, or you use nested or parent/child relationships. I favor "duplicating" the data over the relationships.

Comment: @AndreiStefan thanks for confirming. just to put into context, this is part of an api implementation which has a HAL representation object coming back. what  i ended up doing was returning linked document ids (children) as part of the main record and passing the full comma separated list of children ids in the linked urls (which is the one that makes this call to get all the relevant records). that works for now